# iOS UItableviewcell has no animation when tapped

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell

I have a UITableView Cell with four rows that users can click and it brings them to a web page. The problem is when users click on a cell, it doesn't turn blue, showing the user it has been clicked. The cells work fine in that when clicked you go to a web page delegate. But I would like the cell to turn a color when touched so they know what cell they clicked. Below is the code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section      {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return 4;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor      = [UIColor grayColor];
cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:19];
cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode  = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

cellHasStoreLink = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should either this:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
```

or something like this before `return cell`:

```
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
[bgColorView release];
```

Comment: Neither of those worked. I think the problem has to do with the cells having text in them that comes from a json file.

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor      = [UIColor grayColor];
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:19];